# Azure Files with Terraform (using CSI driver)

Tags: azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, azure-files

I want to share persistent volumes between many AKS pods using the Azure Files CSI driver.

Is this possible using Terraform ?
Someone has a documentation to implement this ?

(I see that CSI driver is in preview on Azure)